# Using gsutil rsync to copy new files only

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I have this little script running on a windows machine that syncs down files from google storage bucket and sends the new files to a printer hot folder. The file disappears from printers hot directory as soon as it is printed. As you can see the script uses a backup directory to compare each and every file to make sure only new files are sent to the printer. This solution works well, but clearly not very efficient for large volume of files. Just wondering if  rsync has options to copy only new files from bucket since the last run.

```
@echo off
SET SOURCE=%1
SET DESTINATION=%2
SET HOTDIR=%3
SET BACKUPDIR=%4

SET GSUTIL_INST_DIR=C:\PRINT
SET PARENT_DIR=C:\PRINT
SET GSUTIL=%GSUTIL_INST_DIR%\google-cloud-sdk-386.0.0-windows-x86_64-bundled-python\google-cloud-sdk\bin\gsutil
SET GSUTIL=%GSUTIL% -m

call %GSUTIL% rsync -d -C %SOURCE%/ %DESTINATION%/
:: Compare each file before sending it to hot directory
for /f  %%F in ('dir /b "%DESTINATION%"') do (
    if not exist "%BACKUPDIR%\%%F" (
    XCOPY /Y /F "%DESTINATION%\%%F" "%HOTDIR%\%%F*" 
    )
)
robocopy %DESTINATION% %BACKUPDIR% /MIR

SET CONFIRMATION= "%DATE% %TIME% %SOURCE%  to  %HOTDIR%"
```

Answer (score 0):

> Just wondering if rsync has options to copy only new files from bucket
> since the last run.

Below solution may work for your scenario:

- Maintain last script run timestamp history in some local file
- List the GCS objects(files) in sorted order by date

  gsutil ls -l gs://your-bucket/ | sort -k 2
- The above command will give the timestamp of the objects added, so you can pipe the output and filter the object list based on the timestamp stored in history file.